# Comparing contents of files for groupings of words

Tags: c

Background:
I am currently working on a project. The main objective is to read files and compare groupings of words. Only user interaction will be to specify group length. My programs are placed into a directory. Inside that directory, there will be multiple textfiles(Up to 30). I use
system("ls /home/..... > inputfile.txt");

```
    system("ls /home/..... > inputfile.txt");
```

From there, I open the files from inputfile.txt to read for their contents.
Now to the actual question/problem part.
The method I am using for this is a queue because FIFO. (Code "link.c":http://pastebin.com/rLpVGC00

#### `link.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linkedlist.h"

struct linkedList
{  
   char *data;
   int key;
   int left;
   int right;
   int size;
};

LinkedList createLinkedList(int size)
{
   LinkedList newLL = malloc(sizeof *newLL);
   newLL->data  = malloc(sizeof(int) * (size+1));
   newLL->size  = size;
   newLL->left  = 0;
   newLL->right = 0;
   return newLL;
}

bool isFull(LinkedList LL)
{
    return abs(abs(LL->left)- abs(LL->right)) == LL->size;
}

void insertFront(LinkedList LL, char  *newInfo)
{
    if(isFull(LL)) 
    {
        printf("FULL");
        exit(1);
    }

   LL->data[((--(LL->left) % LL->size) + LL->size) % LL->size] = newInfo;
}

bool isEmpty(LinkedList LL)
{
    return LL->left == LL->right;
}

const char * removeEnd(LinkedList LL)
{
    if(isEmpty(LL))
    {
        return "EMPTY";
        //exit(1);
    }
    return LL->data[((--(LL->right) % LL->size) + LL->size) % LL->size];
}
```

I get two warnings when I compile with link.c and my main (Start11.c)

```
    link.c: In function ‘insertFront’:
    link.c:39:64: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    LL->data[((--(LL->left) % LL->size) + LL->size) % LL->size] = newInfo;
                                                            ^
    link.c: In function ‘removeEnd’:
    link.c:54:5: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 return LL->data[((--(LL->right) % LL->size) + LL->size) % LL->size];
 ^
```

FULL start11.c code: http://pastebin.com/eskn5yxm  . 
From bulk of read() function that I have questions about:

```
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");

  //We want two word or three word or four word PHRASES

  for (i = 0; fgets(name, 100, fp) != NULL && i < 31; i++) 
  {
     char *token = NULL; //setting to null before using it to strtok
     token = strtok(name, ":");
     strtok(token, "\n");//Getting rid of that dirty \n that I hate
     strcat(fnames[i], token);
     char location[350];
     //Copying it back to a static array to avoid erros with fopen()
     strcpy(location, fnames[i]);
     //Opening the files for their contents
     fpp = fopen(location, "r");
     printf("\nFile %d:[%s] \n", i+1,  fnames[i]);

     char* stringArray[400];
     //Reading the actual contents
     int y;
     for(j = 0;  fgets(info,1600,fpp) != NULL && j < 1600; j++)
     {   
         for( char *token2 = strtok(info," "); token2 != NULL; token2 =  strtok(NULL, " ") )
         {
            puts(token2);
            ++y;
            stringArray[y] = strdup(token2); 
            insertFront(index[i],stringArray[y]); 
         }      
         }
         }
        //Comparisons

         char take[20010],take2[200100], take3[200100],take4[200100];
         int x,z;
         int count, count2;
         int groupV,groupV2;
         for(x = 0; x < 10000; ++x)
         {
           if(removeEnd(index[0])!= "EMPTY")
           {
              take[x] = removeEnd(index[0]);
           }
           if(removeEnd(index[1])!= "EMPTY")
           {
               take2[x] = removeEnd(index[1]);
           }
           if(removeEnd(index[2])!= "EMPTY")
           {
               take3[x] = removeEnd(index[2]);
           }
        }
          for(z = 0; z < 10; z++)
          {
              if(take[z] == take2[z])
              {
               printf("File 1 and File 2 are similar\n");
               ++count;
              if(count == groupL)
              {
                 ++groupV;
              }
         }
              if(take[z] == take3[z])
                {
                  printf("File 1 and File 3 are similar\n");
                   ++count2;
                   if(count == groupL)
                    {
                        ++groupV2;
                    }
                 }
              }
```

Are those two warnings before the reason why when I try to compare the files it'll not be correct? (Yes I realize I "hardcoded" the comparisons. That is just temporary till I get some of this down...)
I'll post header files as a comment. Won't let me post more than two links.
Additional notes:
removeEnd() returns "EMPTY" if there is if there is nothing left to remove.
insertFront() is a void function.
Before I created this account so I can post, I read a previous question regarding strttok and how if I want to insert something I have to strdup() it.
I have not added my free functions to my read() function. I will do that last too.

#### `start.h` ([pastebin.com/NTnEAPYE](http://pastebin.com/NTnEAPYE))

```
#ifndef START_H
#define START_H
#include "linkedlist.h"

void read(LinkedList LL,char* filename, int lineL);
#endif
```

#### `linkedlist.h` ([pastebin.com/ykzbnCTV](http://pastebin.com/ykzbnCTV))

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

typedef int bool;
typedef struct linkedList *LinkedList;

LinkedList createLinkedList(int size);

bool isFull(LinkedList LL);

void insertFront(LinkedList LL, char *newInfo);

const char * removeEnd(LinkedList LL);

bool isEmpty(LinkedList LL);

#endif
```

Comment: start.h: http://pastebin.com/NTnEAPYE

Comment: linkedlist.h: http://pastebin.com/ykzbnCTV

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question — not in pastebin.  Stuff in pastebin tends to go missing, rendering questions inscrutable in a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is around the `removeEnd` (resp. `insertFrom`) function:

```
const char * removeEnd(LinkedList LL)
{
  if (...)
    return "EMPTY";
  else
     return LL->data[xxx];
```

you return a `const char *` in the first return but a `char` in the second return, hence the warning, which is a serious one.

And when you compare return value to `"EMPTY"` in the caller, it's just wrong: you should use `strcmp` instead of comparing arrays which may be the same depending on compilers which group same strings in the same location, but only by chance (and not portable!)